# Returning a Pointer to buffer from function

Tags: c

I have function that reads the sensor data over I2C and fills that data in buffer.

```
void ADXLGetData(ADXLData_t * adxldataptr) 
{
    Buffer[0] = ADD_X0;
    i2cRead(slave_add, reg_add,&buffer[0]);
    adxldataptr->datax0 =buffer[1];
    adxldataptr->datax1 = buffer[2];
    adxldataptr->datay0 = buffer[3];
    adxldataptr->datay1 = buffer[4];
    adxldataptr->dataz0 = buffer[5];
    adxldataptr->dataz1 = buffer[6];
}
```

where ADXLData_t is my structure of 6 bytes and buffer is declared as below in my header file.

```
 volatile char buffer[12];
```

and other is like below.

```
char * ADXLGetData(void)
{ 
    ADXLData_t *adxldataptr;
    buffer[0] =  ADD_X0;
    i2cRead(slave_add, reg_add,&buffer[0]);
    adxldataptr = (ADXLData_t*)&buffer[0];
    return adxldataptr;
}
```

Both will be reading same sensor data. as i read data over timer interval of 1ms( that are four sensors including this) i am getting fault while using first function.
But if i use second function my program runs smooth.
In first function I get data perfectly over 5-6 iterations.
but in second I am not getting perfect data.
I am calling the functions as below.

for calling first function

```
  ADXLData_t Acc1dataptr; 
  ADXLGetData(&Acc1dataptr);
```

for the second

```
 ADXLData_t * Acc1dataptr;
 Acc1dataptr = (ADXLData_t*) ADXLGetData();
```

This functions are called in another file not in same file , But I have included all the required files.

could please tell what i am doing wrong.?

Comment: How is `Buffer` allocated? What type is it?

Comment: We need some more information here. How is buffer allocated?

Comment: Your second function is declared to return `char *` but is returning `ADXLData_t *`

Comment: Is it meant to be `buffer`and `Buffer` the same?

Comment: buffer or Buffer count as same, It's my typo mistake here. Sorry for that confusion.

In first function I am passing a char pointer and in second I am returning char pointer. 
The buffer is `unsigned char Buffer[12]` .
thanks,

Comment: @evaet1 sigh, please show _where_ `buffer` is declared. Is it a global variable?

Comment: Please edit the question with relevant details rather than posting them as comments. @evaet1

Comment: _But if i use second function my program runs smooth. In first function I get data perfectly over 5-6 iterations. but in second I am not getting perfect data._ this sounds somewhat contradictory to me.

Comment: Can you show us how these functions are called in your code? Have you allocated memory for `ADXLData_t * adxldataptr` in first case?

Comment: @ Vagish , Thanks, 
 I have edited the question with how I am calling the function.

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong. In the second variant returning a pointer to the global `buffer` variable ist not particularly elegant because it may cause problems if `buffer` is reused after the call to `ADXLGetData()`. Right after `Acc1dataptr = (ADXLData_t*) ADXLGetData();` `Acc1dataptr` points to `buffer`; if then you call any function that modifies `buffer`, `Acc1dataptr` will point that modified data in `buffer`. But we can't tell more, because we'd need to see more of your code.

Comment: @MichaelWalz, I can provide my code whole , but not here. as I am developing for my project,. But I can share finding after error get resolved so that other can also benefit from it. 
I can mail or chat in personally if possible so that I can resolve it.

Comment: @evaet1 once you have found the problem, you can answer your own question here.

Comment: @MichaelWalz, what I was telling that, I can mail you the code required to understand the problem as I can't post here.

Comment: @evaet1 no need form mailing put it on http://pastebin.com/

Comment: sure ll do ,but how to share link, to you in person